# How to correctly create a list of reactive datasets in a Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I currently have several different reactive datasets that are created by my Shiny app and am trying to build a function that will pull the appropriate dataset and `renderHTML`. I am currently struggling with subsetting this list of reactive datasets that I am creating.

I have tried using a list of reactive datasets (`listofsurveydata`) below but always get the `Error in .subset2: no such index at level 1` error message.

```
lcSurveyDataSplit <- function(panelnumber){

colind <- grep(input$lcstateselect[panelnumber],colnames(inputTable$data))

predata <- inputTable$data %>%
  filter(
    grepl(search,.[[colind]]),
    is.null(input$lccategoryselect)| Category %in% input$lccategoryselect,
    is.null(input$lcsubcategoryselect)| Sub_category %in% input$lcsubcategoryselect,
    is.null(input$lcquestionselect)| Question %in% input$lcquestionselect
  )
  }

  lcsurveydata1 <- reactive({lcSurveyDataSplit(1)})
  lcsurveydata2 <- reactive({lcSurveyDataSplit(2)})
  lcsurveydata3 <- reactive({lcSurveyDataSplit(3)})
  lcsurveydata4 <- reactive({lcSurveyDataSplit(4)})

  lcSplitPanel <- function(panelnumber){ # sfnumber stands for "surveyFunction number"

listofsurveydata <- list(lcsurveydata1(), lcsurveydata2(), lcsurveydata3(), lcsurveydata4())

surveyFunction <- listofsurveydata[[panelnumber]]

questioncount <- nrow(surveyFunction)

state <- grep(input$lcstateselect[panelnumber], colnames(inputTable$data))

survey <- character(0)

i = 1

while (i <= questioncount) {

  category = surveyFunction[i,2]
  subcategory = surveyFunction[i,3]
  question = surveyFunction[i,4]
  answer = gsub("[\r\n]", "</br>", surveyFunction[i,state])

  if (length(grep(category,survey, fixed = T)) > 0) {

    survey <- paste0(survey,"</br>",
                     "</br><b>", subcategory, "</b>",
                     "</br><b>", question, "</b>",
                     "</br><i>", answer, "</i>","</br>")

  } else {

    survey <- paste0(survey,"</br>",
                     "<b><u>",category, "</u></b>",
                     "</br></br><b>", subcategory, "</b>",
                     "</br><b>", question, "</b>",
                     "</br><i>", answer, "</i>","</br>")
  }

  i = i + 1

}

HTML(paste0("<h4><b>",input$lcstateselect[panelnumber],"</b></h4>",survey))

  }

  output$lcstate1 <- renderUI({lcSplitPanel(1)})  
  output$lcstate2 <- renderUI({lcSplitPanel(2)})
  output$lcstate3 <- renderUI({lcSplitPanel(3)})  
  output$lcstate4 <- renderUI({lcSplitPanel(4)})
```

I have been able to narrow down the error to these two lines because the code works fine if I don't subset the data and make literal references to the datasets in `listofsurveydata`:

```
listofsurveydata <- list(lcsurveydata1(), lcsurveydata2(), lcsurveydata3(), lcsurveydata4())

surveyFunction <- listofsurveydata[[panelnumber]]
```

Ideally, I don't want to create a new function for each output object so I was wondering how I should go about solving this error?

Comment: I would say that the `panelnumber` value your are trying to use within your function is not in the range of the indexes of `listofsurveydata` (e.g. 1 to 4). Thus, surveyfunction corresponds to anyone.

Comment: @ElieKerArno but I end up calling `lcSplitPanel` below it only with parameters 1 to 4.